# Webclient Multipage POST & HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, webclient

So I am trying to scrape a website the issue is that they are all post requests though the whole searching process.

So here is the progression of sites I am trying to send post responses to... 
1) https://www20.state.nj.us/LPS_spoff/SetSession 
- Reason Looks like the site wants you to accept the terms first so I send a I accept post response. If I don't do this the other sites following will redirect.

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data1 = new NameValueCollection();
    data1["submit"] = "I accept";
    var response1 = wb.UploadValues("https://www20.state.nj.us/LPS_spoff/SetSession", "POST", data1);

    // more code here to be show later
}
```

The above works and gets to the next page. So Now I can open,

2) https://www20.state.nj.us/LPS_spoff/geographicsearch.jsp - this link without being redirected and really don't need this link not sure If I need to send another post but... what I really want is

3) https://www20.state.nj.us/LPS_spoff/findDriver - this results page from any selections...

Here is the form one would manually submit for the page...

```
<form name="gsm" method="post" action="/LPS_spoff/findDriver"></form>
    <input type="hidden" name="screen" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="county" value=" 01 ">
    <input type="hidden" name="countyname" value=" ATLANTIC ">
    <input type="hidden" name="pmonth" value="  ">
    <input type="hidden" name="pday" value="  ">
    <input type="hidden" name="pyr" value="  ">

    <tbody><tr><td align="center" colspan="4"> You chose <b> ATLANTIC </b> County.
    </td></tr><tr><td align="center" colspan="4"> You can either submit this search using all of
            <b>&nbsp; ATLANTIC </b> County by pressing &nbsp;
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td><td></td></tr>
```

Here is what I tried total:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
{
    var data1 = new NameValueCollection();
    data1["submit"] = "I accept";
    var response1 = wb.UploadValues("https://www20.state.nj.us/LPS_spoff/SetSession", "POST", data1);
    var data = new NameValueCollection();
    data["screen"] = "1";
    data["county"] =  "01";
    data["countyname"] = "ATLANTIC";
    data["pmonth"] = " ";
    data["pday"] = " ";
    data["pyr"] = " ";
    data["Submit"] = "Submit";
    var response = wb.UploadValues("https://www20.state.nj.us/LPS_spoff/findDriver", "POST", data);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(response));
    File.WriteAllText("temp.txt", Encoding.Default.GetString(response));
}
```

The goal is to get to the results page and parse it with HTMLagilitypack.

The code above outputs a file temp.txt that is list the same as site 1) on the list above... and not the results it seems to redirect.

To summarize:
I want to get the results for offenders but they are all post responses and I need help navigating to the results page efficiently.

Note: I know I can probably use selenium but that's way too much overhead for what I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was cookies associated with the website that are responsible for the redirection.

To bypass this I used

```
  var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
```

And everything seems to be working fine. Check website for cookies if this happens to you.